# R Polygon Plot Not Shading to X Axis

Tags: r, plot, polygon

Using R and polygon I'm trying to shade the area under the line of a plot from the line to the x-axis and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

The shading is using some point in the middle of the y range to shade from, not 0, the x-axis.

The data set ratioresults is a zoo object but I don't think that's the issue since I tried coercing the y values to as.numeric and as.vector and got the same results.

Code:

```
plot(index(ratioresults),ratioresults$ratio, type="o", col="red")
polygon(c(1,index(ratioresults),11),c(0, ratioresults$ratio, 0) , col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Supply your data, or something that exhibits the problem. Its likely to be because the axes aren't what you think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's `index(ratioresults)`? For a simple zoo object I see:

```
> index(x)
[1] "2003-02-01" "2003-02-03" "2003-02-07" "2003-02-09" "2003-02-14"
```

which is a vector of `Date` objects. You are trying to prepend/append values of 1 and 11 to this vector. Its not going to work.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
x=zoo(matrix(runif(11),ncol=1),as.Date("2012-08-01") + 0:10)
colnames(x)="ratio"
plot(index(x),x$ratio,type="o",col="red",ylim=c(0,1))
polygon(index(x)[c(1,1:11,11)],c(0,x$ratio,0),col="red")
```

Differences from yours:

1. I call my thing `x`.
2. I set `ylim` on the plot - I don't know how your plot managed to start at 0 on the Y axis.
3. I complete the polygon using the x-values of the first and 11th (last) point, rather than 1 and 11 themselves.

Comment: Thanks a ton for such a detailed answer.  Worked like a charm and I understand the issue clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#With an example dataset: please provide one when you need help!
ratioresults<-as.zoo(runif(10,0,1))
plot(index(ratioresults),ratioresults, type="o", col="red", 
     xaxs="i",yaxs="i", ylim=c(0,2))
polygon(c(index(ratioresults),rev(index(ratioresults))),
        c(as.vector(ratioresults),rep(0,length(ratioresults))),col="red")
```

The issue with your question is that the x-axis is not a line defined by a given y value by default, so one way to fill under a curve to the x-axis using `polygon` would be to define a y values for the x-axis using `ylim` (here I chose 0). Whatever value you choose you will want to specify that the plot stop exactly at the value using `yaxs="i"`.
You also have to construct your polygon with the value you chose for you x-axis.